# Relation between the eigenvectors of $A$ and $A^TA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is there a relation between the *eigenvectors* of matrix $A$ and of matrix $A^TA$?

This question is related to eigenvectors, *not* eigenvalues. Further, the sizes of matrices $A$ and $A^TA$ are different if $A$ is not a square matrix. Thus, my question has no relation to the question about eigenvalues of $A$ ans $A^T$.

Comment: Do you mean eigenvalues are same?

Comment: If you're asking if $A$ and $A^TA$ share the same set of eigenspaces, then this really comes down to "do $A$ and $A^T$ share the same set of eigenspaces?"  And the answer to that is "no".  Just consider $\pmatrix{1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0}$ and $\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0}$.  The *eigenvalues* on the other hand...

Comment: $Ax = \lambda_1 x, A^TAy = \lambda_2 y$

$\to  A^T \lambda_1 y  = \lambda_2 y$

I think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no simple relation between eigenvectors of $A$ and of $A^*A$ unless $A$ is normal. For example, if 
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0},
$$
$A$ has only one dimensional eigenvector subspace spanned by $[1,0]^T$, but $A^*A=0$ so any nonzero 2-vector is its eigenvector. Even if $A$ is diagonalizable, the eigenspaces of $A$ and $A^*A$ can be completely different.

If $A$ is normal, then $A=UDU^*$ for a unitary $U$ and diagonal $D$, so $A^*A=U|D|^2U^*$ is the spectral decomposition of $A^*A$.

However, there is a simple relation between left singular vectors of $A$ and the eigenvectors of $A^*A$ as indicated in another answer.

Comment: The diagonal matrix gets squared.

Comment: @Ian Yep thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Let $A=U\Lambda V^\top$, $U$, $\Lambda$ and $V$ are respectively left eigenvectors, eigenvalues and right eigenvectors.

$$A^\top A=U\Lambda V^\top V \Lambda U^\top=U\Lambda^2 U^\top$$

So what are the eigenvalues of $A^\top A$ ?

Comment: You mean that $A=U\Lambda V^T$ is the **SVD** of $A$, not its spectral decomposition.

Comment: Yes, indeed. It's the svd

Comment: Ok, so the columns of $U$ and $V$ are left and right singular vectors of $A$, not eigenvectors.